# How to deal with react-hot-toast in next js 14 when I am dealing with server actions?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, next.js

In the action.js file I am calling "use server" and dealing with server actions. Here I have created a function which responsible for updating users. After successfully updating I am returning "User Update Successfully"

```
export const updateUser = async (prevState, formData) => {
  const { id, name, email, number, role, status } =
    Object.fromEntries(formData);

  const newUser = await query({
    query:
      "UPDATE users SET  name = ?, email = ?, number = ?, role = ?, status = ? WHERE id = ?",
    values: [name, email, number, role, status, id],
  });

  if (!newUser) {
    return "User Update Failed";
  }
  if (newUser) {
    // redirect("/dashboard/grit/edit");
    revalidatePath("/dashboard/grit/edit");
    return "User Update Successfully";
  }
};
```

On the page.js file I can catch the returning value but It is not working properly. I want to know how I can smoothly deal with react hot toast

```
use client";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import { MdModeEdit } from "react-icons/md";
import { updateUser } from "@/app/lib/actions";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
const UpdateUser = ({ id, name, email, number, role, status }) => {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(updateUser, undefined);

  function Submit() {
    const { pending } = useFormStatus();

    const notify = () => {
      toast.success("Successfully Updated!", {
        style: {
          background: "#228B22",
          color: "#fff",
        },
      });

      document.getElementById(id).close();
    };

    return (
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-sm btn-neutral text-white h-[6vh] w-[35vh] rounded-md "
        disabled={pending}
        onClick={notify}
      >
        {pending ? "Updating..." : "Update User"}
      </button>
    );
  }
```

I am trying to solve the code where I want to know how I can deal with react-hot-toast with next.js 14 server actions.

I expect someone to help me solve the issue I am dealing with.

Comment: Please share code in question itself.

Comment: Okay. I have shared the code, you can check it.

Comment: @SiratulIslam The code you have provided is either incomplete, or syntactically incorrect. Please refractor your question to fit the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).